# Return web info from Google search into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am trying do a Google search for information related to a listing of companies, names and people in an Excel sheet and return short snippets of text into the Excel workbook.

I call up an Internet webpage and search from column "A", create a new workbook "1" that the data can be pasted into.

I have been unable to return the snippets of text from the Google search into column "B" and "C."

```vb
Sub ImportWebData()

j = 1
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

With Sheets("Data ReCalc")

    RowCount = 2
    Do While .Range("A" & RowCount) <> ""
        CellName = .Range("A" & RowCount)
        url = CellName

        'get web page
        ie.Navigate2 url
        Do While ie.readyState <> 4 Or _
            ie.Busy = True
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        DestSh.Name = j

        Sheets(j).Select
        Cells.Select
        Range("A1").Select
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
          "URL;" & CellName, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
            .Name = CellName
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
        End With

        j = j + 1

        Sheets("Data ReCalc").Select
        RowCount = RowCount + 1

    Loop

End With
ie.Quit

End Sub
```

There are many alternatives and if the code was able to take snapshots and print to pdf, or if I could scrape the text from the first five listings and return that info into a new worksheet, that would all work for my purposes.

Comment: When your macro code executes, does it create a "2" tab, etc.?  Have you single-stepped through your macro code?  Can you edit your question to show what results you **did** get in your workbook?

Comment: Hey Mark! Thanks for the response, I am getting a stall out on the cycling through the webpages. I will get IE to pop up, but do not get any additional cycling through the next searches.